# How to keccak256 multiple types in web3js to match Solidity keccak256?

Tags: solidity, web3js, sha3, keccak

if I `keccak256(string1, address1)` in `Solidity`, and then use `web3.sha3(string1, address1)` in `web3.js`, I get different results, even though when I do both with only `string1` as a single argument, they are the same results. I have tried passing `{encoding: 'hex'}` to the web3 call but it still gives different results.

Does anyone know how to make `web3.sha3(...args)`, with any arguments (uint, address, string, etc) exactly equal to `keccak256` in Solidity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find [the function in this issue](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/445) to work for all cases (apart from negative numbers, as you will see in the comments in the issue):

```
function keccak256(...args) {
  args = args.map(arg => {
    if (typeof arg === 'string') {
      if (arg.substring(0, 2) === '0x') {
          return arg.slice(2)
      } else {
          return web3.toHex(arg).slice(2)
      }
    }

    if (typeof arg === 'number') {
      return leftPad((arg).toString(16), 64, 0)
    } else {
      return ''
    }
  })

  args = args.join('')

  return web3.sha3(args, { encoding: 'hex' })
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this function http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#soliditysha3?

Comment: seems as if this requires left pad package. I receive "leftPad is not defined"

Comment: Worked for me with [left-pad npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/left-pad) installed

Answer (score 10):

You can use [web3.utils.soliditySha3()](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#soliditysha3)

Alternatively you can try this way:

```
web3.sha3(web3.utils.toHex(string1) + address1, {encoding:"hex"});
```

Note that `address1` should not be prefixed with 0x.

Example:

```
> web3.sha3(web3.utils.toHex("test1") + "0AbdAce70D3790235af448C88547603b945604ea", {encoding:"hex"});
"0xd7ced52b610c8794965f5bb365f280999a9790b147bd0dfc70dea6edb2616c15"
```

Produces the same result as this code in Solidity:

```
keccak256(abi.encodePacked("test1", 0x0AbdAce70D3790235af448C88547603b945604ea));
```

> Does anyone know how to make web3.sha3(...args), with any arguments (uint, address, string, etc) exactly equal to keccak256 in Solidity?

You need to make sure that the 1st argument that you pass to [web3.sha3()](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3sha3) function is equal to the [tightly packed](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html#non-standard-packed-mode) arguments for [keccak256](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=keccak256#mathematical-and-cryptographic-functions) function in Solidity. The easiest way is to use [web3.toHex()](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3tohex) for each argument (except addresses as they are already in hex), then concatenate the results and set encoding to hex in the options for `web3.sha3()` as I've shown in the example.

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is to use `web3.utils.soliditySha3`.

But the way to use it is what makes all the difference.

```
const theValueYouNeed = web3.utils.soliditySha3(
{ type: 'bytes32', value: theBytes32Value },
{ type: 'address', value: theAddressValue },
{ type: 'bytes32', value: 'IfYouAreDirectlyPuttingValueUseQuotes' });
```

This way you will get the same result as the value you get from the Solidity function below:

```
function hashThat(bytes32 theBytes32Value, address theAddressValue, bytes32 anotherValue) public view returns(bytes32 hashedValue){
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(theBytes32Value, theAddressValue, anotherValue));
}
```

Note: I am using web3@1.2.1 and solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0

Comment: This has to be considered the correct answer!

Answer (score 3):

`soliditySha3` will do the trick:

```js
const hashKey = web3.utils.soliditySha3('string', object.param,'rewardAmount', string, address);
```

Answer (score 3):

in js application, require "left-pad" module,such as :**let leftPad = require('left-pad');**

```
function T_keccak256(...args){
args = args.map(arg => {
    if(typeof arg === 'string'){
        if(arg.substring(0,2) === '0x'){
            return arg.slice(2)
        }else {
            return web3.fromAscii(arg).slice(2)
        }
    }
    if(typeof arg === 'number'){
        return leftPad((arg).toString(16),64,0)

    }else {
        return ''
    }
})
args = args.join('');
return web3.sha3(args, { encoding: 'hex'});
```

in Solidity ^5.0，use **keccak256(abi.encodePacked(arg1,arg2,...))** .