# Solidity's keccak256 hash doesn't match WEB3 keccak hash

Tags: solidity, web3js, hash, keccak, hash-algorithm

**TL;DR**: I have a method in a contract to calculate a keccak256 hash, and I'm trying to replicate it in Web3, but the hashes don't match. My problem is very similar to the one in [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24093/keccak3-in-solidity-and-in-web3-different-hashes-for-an-address-type-field/24098), but the answers there didn't help me. It could be an encoding issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

---

I was trying to hash three parameters like this:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
contract Test {
    function makeHash(uint intValue, string calldata strValue) public view returns (bytes32) {
        bytes32 myHash = keccak256(abi.encode(intValue, strValue, msg.sender));
        return myHash;
    }
}
```

Calling `makeHash(1, 'test1')` for this address `0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4` returns `0x94822408407fb535100a4152f8709ed58507e1b3dfd32798d25051065f680d64`

In Web3, I tried to concatenate the values in a string (**I realize this is wrong now**, but also not sure how to do it in web3): `web3.utils.keccak256("1test10x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4")` returns `0xcd347147b43e04263a58ca2b6d0f0aa8a3e0b00bd02c0e9bbee008aad68b1bf0`

From this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/74082/68459) I also tried this method:

```
web3.utils.soliditySha3(
    { type: 'uint', value: 1 },
    { type: 'string', value: 'test1' },
    { type: 'address', value: '0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4' }
)
```

it returns `0x0aca86dcfc0a652e35268737960c05e51eb03dbfc4c175fd3ca094a2e99e180c`

---

**Since all the methods returned different hashes I decided to test to hash just the string in both contract and web3, but even then they generate different hashes.**

```
bytes32 myHash = keccak256(abi.encode(strValue));
```

Using the line aboce in the contract, calling `makeHash('test1')` returns `0xf5e2ed7011d2249ef10becf6f745e4b900ab43c0dc529b97d308f25bb36416d0`

However in web3 all those methods returned the same hash:

```
web3.utils.keccak256("test1")
web3.utils.sha3Raw('test1')
web3.utils.sha3('test1')
web3.utils.soliditySha3('test1')
web3.utils.soliditySha3Raw('test1')
// Tried encoding
web3.utils.sha3('test1', {encoding: 'String'})
web3.utils.sha3('test1', {encoding: 'hex'})
web3.utils.sha3('test1', {encoding: 'string'})
// Tried converting to hex
web3.utils.soliditySha3Raw(web3.utils.asciiToHex('test1'))
web3.utils.keccak256(web3.utils.asciiToHex('test1'))
// Tried from this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/74082/68459
web3.utils.soliditySha3({ type: 'string', value: 'test1' })
```

They all return `0x6d255fc3390ee6b41191da315958b7d6a1e5b17904cc7683558f98acc57977b4`

---

Also, decided to try to replicate `abi.encode` in web3 by using `web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter(String, 'test1')` but it always returns an error:

```
    if (type.match(paramTypeBytesArray) || type.match(paramTypeNumberArray)) {
             ^
Uncaught TypeError: type.match is not a function
    at ABICoder.formatParam (..\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\web3-eth-abi\src\index.js:255:1)
    at ..\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\web3-eth-abi\src\index.js:117:1
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at ABICoder.encodeParameters (..\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\web3-eth-abi\src\index.js:105:1)
    at ABICoder.encodeParameter (..\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\web3-eth-abi\src\index.js:88:1)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:0:14
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:274:15)
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:128:14)
    at runScript (..\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\console.js:270:1)
    at Console.interpret (..\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\console.js:285:1)
    at bound (domain.js:426:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:439:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:760:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at REPLServer.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:329:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:658:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:999:14)
    at REPLServer.self._ttyWrite (repl.js:851:9)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:205:10)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
```

Comment: Have you tried with `abi.encodePacked` instead of `abi.encode`? Maybe here you could find something useful https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/72199/testing-sha256abi-encodepacked-argument.

Comment: I haven't yet, and I will try it. But I was keeping away from `abi.encodePacked` because of a mention of hash collision when using more than one dynamic data (not sure what that means). https://solidity-by-example.org/hashing/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `abi.encode` function encode its parameters for a contract call using Solidity's ABI [specs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/abi-spec.html). For fixed size types like uintXXX, bool, address, it's quite easy, just pad them to 32 bytes; for dynamic types it's complicated.

The equivalent to this Solidity code:

```
bytes32 myHash = keccak256(abi.encode('test1'));
```

in JavaScript would be:

```
const encoded = web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(['string'],['test1'])
const hash = web3.utils.sha3(encoded, {encoding: 'hex'})
console.log(hash)
```

If you are curious, 'test1' ABI-encoded is:

```
0x
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020   // offset
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005   // length
7465737431000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000   // data
```

In your case, the equivalent to `makeHash` in JavaScript is:

```
const encoded = web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(['uint256', 'string', 'address'],[1234, 'country roads', 0x44444..])
const hash = web3.utils.sha3(encoded, {encoding: 'hex'})
```

Comment: So I fed this binary of the required 256-bit hash-input into SpeedCrunch and it is 2.00000000000000000000e+129. I guess that's why better to use encodePacked unless you have things in 256-bit format already.

Comment: @Tomachi Sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way in Python to do this in case you are still looking for the answer. Here is the code below. Here is how you can do this in Python. I'm using the `web3.keccak` method of brownie which is similar to `web3.py`.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from brownie import web3
from eth_abi import encode

encoded_data = encode(
    ["uint", "string", "address"],
    [1, "test1", "0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4"],
)


print(web3.keccak(encoded_data).hex())
print(web3.sha3(encoded_data).hex())
```

- Here is the output

```py
0x94822408407fb535100a4152f8709ed58507e1b3dfd32798d25051065f680d64
0x94822408407fb535100a4152f8709ed58507e1b3dfd32798d25051065f680d64
```

[image]

**Edit**

- [ape](https://docs.apeworx.io/ape/stable/) is gaining popularity so here is how you can do this `ape`.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from ape import networks
from eth_abi import encode

web3 = networks.provider._web3

encoded_data = encode(
    ["uint", "string", "address"],
    [1, "test1", "0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4"],
)


print(web3.keccak(encoded_data).hex())
>>> 0x94822408407fb535100a4152f8709ed58507e1b3dfd32798d25051065f680d64
```

Comment: More info can be found here https://eth-abi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/encoding.html