# What is the equivalent of keccak256 in solidity?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js

I am going to get the same value that is produced by keccak256 in solidity.

This is the code in my solidity file and I want to get the same value in the javascript file using `ethers` or `web3`.

```
bytes32 node = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(nodeString));
```

I got the same value of `abi.encodePacked(nodeString))` by using `ethers.utils.solidityPack`.

```
const abiEncodedPackedString = ethers.utils.solidityPack(['string'], [nodeString]);
```

But when I tried `ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256`, the result wasn't the same as `node` in solidity.

```
const nodeInJavascript = ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(['string], [abiEncodePackedString]);
```

I have also tried `ethers.utils.keccak256(abiEncodePackedString)` but I couldn't get the result either.

Comment: Does this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30024/how-to-keccak256-multiple-types-in-web3js-to-match-solidity-keccak256 answer your question?

Comment: Thanks, @Ismael for your kind comment. I have tried all methods mentioned in the question you linked, but I didn't find a proper method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this from the documentation https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/hashing/.

- `ethers.utils.keccak256`: It accepts a bytes like sequence so you have to convert the string to a byte sequence with `ethers.utils.toUtf8Bytes`

  ```
  ethers.utils.keccak256(ethers.utils.toUtf8Bytes("hola"))
  ```

  > 0x8aca9664752dbae36135fd0956c956fc4a370feeac67485b49bcd4b99608ae41
- `ethers.utils.id`

  ```
  ethers.utils.id("hola")
  ```

  > 0x8aca9664752dbae36135fd0956c956fc4a370feeac67485b49bcd4b99608ae41